# spring boot application ClassNotFoundException FlatMapFunction implementation

Tags: apache-spark

I am submitting a spring boot application to a spark 2 cluster which reads some data from Hive, transforms it using a FlatMapFunction then writes it to Hive. After loading the Hive data it fails with a ClassNotFoundException on the FlatMapFunction.

The code works fine if Spring Boot isn't used. When I convert the project to Spring Boot, using the 'spring-boot-maven-plugin', creating the Spark session as a @Configuration class and injecting it into the main application class which is @SpringBootApplication, I get the error after the data is loaded from Hive.

I am not using Spring to wire together the spark processing code, its done manually long hand. I have tried using an anonymous implementation of the function as well.

Command line

```sh
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 20g --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 12g application.jar
```

From pom.xml

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.ced.spark.patterndetection.Driver</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My classes in the application jar file:

```sh
  2465 Wed Sep 11 08:46:14 NZST 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/com/ced/spark/patterndetection/Analyser.class
  1667 Wed Sep 11 08:46:14 NZST 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/com/ced/spark/patterndetection/Driver.class
  1638 Wed Sep 11 08:46:14 NZST 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/com/ced/spark/patterndetection/SparkSessionConfiguration.class
  2242 Wed Sep 11 08:46:14 NZST 2019 BOOT-INF/classes/com/ced/spark/patterndetection/Transformer.class
```

The application class

```java
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = { org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration.class } )
public class Driver implements CommandLineRunner, Serializable {

  private final SparkSession spark;

  @Inject
  public Driver( SparkSession spark ){
    this.spark = spark;
  }


  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    SpringApplication.run( Driver.class , args );
  }

  @Override
  public void run( String... args ) {

    new Analyser( this.spark , new Transformer( ) ).doit();
  }
}
```

```java
public class Analyser implements Serializable {

  private final SparkSession spark;
  private final Transformer transformer;

  Analyser(  SparkSession spark , Transformer transformer ){
    this.spark = spark;
    this.transformer = transformer;
  }

  void doit(){

    spark.sql( "USE ced_campaign_analysis" );

    final Dataset< Row > dataFrame = spark.sql( "SELECT * FROM src" );
    dataFrame.show();

    final JavaRDD<Row> matchResults = dataFrame.javaRDD().mapPartitions( this.transformer );

    matchResults.collect().stream().forEach( System.out::println );
  }

}
```

The problematic function implementation

```java
public class Transformer implements FlatMapFunction< Iterator<Row>, Row>, Serializable {

  @Override
  public Iterator< Row > call( Iterator< Row > inputs ) {

    final List<Row> outputs = new ArrayList<>();

    while ( inputs.hasNext( ) ) {

      final Row input = inputs.next( );

      final List< String > output  = new ArrayList<>();

      output.add( "qqqq=>"+input.get( 0 ) );
      output.add( "qqqq=>"+input.get( 1 ) );

      outputs.add( RowFactory.create( output.toArray( ) ) );
    }

    return outputs.iterator();
  }
}
```

Comment: While getting a coffee after submitting the post, it dawned on me that it is pretty obvious what is going wrong, my code is in the BOOT-INF directory in the jar file which spark has no knowledge of when it tries to run the function. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: I have seen the answer in this post ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442235/classnotfoundexception-when-executing-spring-boot-application-using-spark-submit`` which uses maven shade plugin to build the jar file. It does work , requires the main class to be specified on the command line.

Comment: Use <Main-Class> rather than <MainClass> in the maven-shade-plugin section in pom.xml so that you don't need to supply the main class on the command line

Comment: Logging with log4j2 stopped working with this answer.   I see these errors on the console and no file is created 
`ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [d]
%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n13 Sep 2019 09:11:29,567  INFO SparkSqlParser:54 - Parsing command: message text
`

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this issue I found a much better way to run a Spring Boot application in Apache Spark: refer https://radanalytics.io/assets/my-first-radanalytics-app/sparkpi-java-spring.html.

The crux of the solution is to specify that the original jar file generated by the spring-boot-maven-plugin is submitted to spark (rather than the modified jar file that runs spring boot)

```java
    final SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder( )
        .config("spark.jars", config.originalJarFile( ) )
        ...
        .getOrCreate( );
```

The name of this jar file is setup by this plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>rename-file</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>rename</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>target/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar.original</sourceFile>
                <destinationFile>target/${project.name}-${project.version}-original.jar</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The jar file name is captured in this property which makes use of maven build parameters

```
jar-file: /home/xxxxxx/jars/@project.name@-@project.version@-original.jar
```